# Microsoft Edge 85.0.564.63 | Bug | Zoom In or Zoom Out with keyboard shortcuts influence all the windows, tabs of the same site domain

Tags: microsoft-edge

**Version:**
Microsoft Edge 85.0.564.63

**Issue:**
Increasing or Decreasing Zoom Levels with keyboard shortcuts influence all the windows, tabs of the same site domain

[GIF That shows the Issue - not allowed to embed it to this post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw7Cv.gif)

**Reproduce Issue:**
Open a new windows or Tab with the same site domain , Zoom in or Zoom out with keyboard shortcuts will change all of the instances of the same site domain.

**Will not occur if you zoom in or zoom out with the touchpad, I dont have regular mouse for Testing**

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: And if you want to do a bug report, you will have to do that with Microsoft

Comment: Thank you at first I haven't found a way to post a a support ticket - but I found the link: https://microsoftedgesupport.microsoft.com/hc/ I'll go and close this issue after I get some response from Them.

Comment: I think it's not an issue. It's just the common browser behavior which is expected. I tested with Edge 85.0.564.63, Chrome and Firefox, the behaviors are all the same. You can also have a try in other browsers and you'll find the same behavior.

Comment: I got reply from Microsoft - "As I understand it, keyboard shortcuts for zoom affect all windows and tabs of the same site domain. That is actually a feature when using zoom but I understand how you can see it as a bug. I do meet with the development team each week and will make sure to share your feedback with them" - you all correct it's a feature , it just seemed weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got reply from Microsoft - "As I understand it, keyboard shortcuts for zoom affect all windows and tabs of the same site domain. That is actually a feature when using zoom but I understand how you can see it as a bug. I do meet with the development team each week and will make sure to share your feedback with them" - you all correct it's a feature

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.